# writing '-' in regular expression django url

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I want to accept in a django url:

```
StoreageLocation/X-YYY-X   (E-152-A , E-112-B)
```

(where X is `[A-Z]` and Y is `[0-9]`)

First I tried to solve for X-YYY with:

```
url(r'^StorageLocation/\[A-Z\-0-9{3}])$', views.StorageLocation, name='StorageLocation'),
```

but that won't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check one upper case letter, then dash, then exactly 3 digits, the dash and a single upper case letter:

```
url(r'^StorageLocation/[A-Z]\-[0-9]{3}\-[A-Z]$', views.StorageLocation, name='StorageLocation'),
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\-[0-9]{3}\-[A-Z]')
>>> pattern.match('E-152-A')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103aba6b0>
>>> pattern.match('E-112-B')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103abab90>
```

Comment: As a side note, case sensitive URLs are always a bad idea.

Comment: @limelights yup, though this was an initial requirement here..thanks.

Comment: @limelights , Thank you very much for your answer.
why is it bad , case sensitive urls?